# How to change color of svg-element back and fourth by clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, click

I want to make an SVG-circle (a sun) that goes from yellow to grey by clicking on it, and then goes back to yellow if you click it again (and so on). I have in different ways been able to make the sun change color by clicking it once, but it won't change back on the second click.

Why doesn't this work? How am I supposed to do it?

Sorry if I am making this post in a wrong way, this is my first post here.

```js
// Trying to make it as one function with if-else

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sun").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("fill") == "yellow") {
      $(this).css({ fill: "grey" });
      $(this).css({ stroke: "grey" });
    } else {
      $("#sun").css({ fill: "yellow" });
      $("#sun").css({ stroke: "orange" });
    }
  });
});




// Trying to have the two clicks in different functions

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sun").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("fill") == "yellow") {
      $(this).css({ fill: "grey" });
      $(this).css({ stroke: "grey" });
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sun").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("fill") == "grey") {
      $("#sun").css({ fill: "yellow" });
      $("#sun").css({ stroke: "orange" });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200">
        <circle id="sun" cx="220" cy="40" r="20" stroke="orange" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Trying to make one function with if-else

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sun").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("fill") == "yellow") {
      $(this).attr("fill", "grey");
      $(this).css({ stroke: "grey" });
    } else {
      $("#sun").attr("fill", "yellow");
      $("#sun").css({ stroke: "orange" });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200">
        <circle id="sun" cx="220" cy="40" r="20" stroke="orange" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
```

It didn't work because `$(this).css` change the inline style (check the html with inspect in your snippet) instead use `$(this).attr` to the change the `fill` attr (not the style `fill`)

Comment: @IngridGomo this is unrelated but no need to make multiple `$(document).ready(function(){` just one and put all those events inside

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Not sure if I understand completely why though. I don't see the problem with changing the inline style. Also, does $(this).attr not change the inline style? I am new to this, so I though inline style and attribute was the same thing, but probably not then. Also thanks for the comment, I'll fix it :)

Comment: @IngridGomo let's take this as example `<circle id="sun" cx="220" cy="40" r="20" stroke="orange" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" style="fill: grey; stroke: grey;" />` the attributes here are id, cx, cy, r, stroke, stroke-width, fill and style the fill and stroke inside style aren't considered attributes but css so when you use `$(this).attr` you change the attribute `fill` but when you use `$(this).css` you change the `fill` inside the `style` attribute. The attributes names that have css proprieties are called `Presentation attributes`

Comment: @IngridGomo lastly the `style` attribute (inline style) has a bigger priority than `Presentation attributes`

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle a class like so:

```js
sun.addEventListener("click",()=>{sun.classList.toggle("night")})
```

```css
#sun{stroke:orange;fill:yellow;}
#sun.night{stroke:black;fill:silver;}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
        <circle id="sun" cx="220" cy="40" r="20" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
      </svg>
```

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit!